# Use pdfx with customized XMP packet

Tags: xetex, luatex, pdfx, xmp

When using `pdfx` for producing PDF/A-1b documents, one should supply the necessary metadata in a file named `_texname_.xmpdata`, which will be translated later to the XMP packet proper, `pdfa.xmpi`. ([manual](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf), pp. 5).

Example `test.xmpdata`:

```
\Title{Test}
\Subject{Random}
\Author{amyspark}
\Keywords{demo\sep test}
\Publisher{See}
\Copyright{\copyright 2016 Amyspark CC-BY-NC-ND}
\CopyrightURL{https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/}
\PublicationType{book}
```

Is it possible to, given this package, make it use a different packet altogether? For example, the one generated by the [Creative Commons "Choose a license" page](https://creativecommons.org/choose/):

```
<?xpacket begin='' id=''?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x='adobe:ns:meta/'>
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
             xmlns:xapRights='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/'>
      <xapRights:Marked>True</xapRights:Marked>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
             xmlns:xapRights='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/'>
      <xapRights:WebStatement rdf:resource='My URL'/>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
             xmlns:xapRights='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/'
             >
        <xapRights:UsageTerms>
            <rdf:Alt>
                <rdf:li xml:lang='x-default' >This work is licensed under a &lt;a rel=&#34;license&#34; href=&#34;http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/&#34;&gt;Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License&lt;/a&gt;.</rdf:li>
                <rdf:li xml:lang='en_US' >This work is licensed under a &lt;a rel=&#34;license&#34; href=&#34;http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/&#34;&gt;Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License&lt;/a&gt;.</rdf:li>
                <rdf:li xml:lang='en' >This work is licensed under a &lt;a rel=&#34;license&#34; href=&#34;http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/&#34;&gt;Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License&lt;/a&gt;.</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
        </xapRights:UsageTerms>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
             xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'>
        <dc:title>
            <rdf:Alt>
              <rdf:li xml:lang='x-default'>Title</rdf:li>
              <rdf:li xml:lang='en_US'>Title</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
        </dc:title>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
      xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns#'>
      <cc:license rdf:resource='http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/'/>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
      xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns#'>
      <cc:attributionName>My name</cc:attributionName>
    </rdf:Description>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=''
      xmlns:cc='http://creativecommons.org/ns#'>
      <cc:morePermissions rdf:resource='Ask permissions URL'/>
    </rdf:Description>
  </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end='r'?>
```

I'm especially interested in the properties describing CC licensing (at the bottom of the file).

Comment: Would improve your question if you could provide 'the one generated by the Creative Commons "Choose a license" page'. PDF/A needs specifically described xmp data. Unless Creative Commons created xmp with proper description for PDF/A compatibility - it can not be inserted inside pdf retaining pdf/a compatibility.